# Fill column values by matching value in each row on column names

Tags: r

I would like to create a data frame like this:

```
Label   Jim Charles Kevin Alan
Charles 0   1       0     0  
Kevin   0   0       1     0
Alan    0   0       0     1
Alan    0   0       0     1
Jim     1   0       0     0
```

I am starting with a data frame where the column names are set and the people's names are listed in the first column, but all the numbers are 0. I want to quickly be able to set some of them to 1 by matching the name listed in the first column to the column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Similar to Ben's answer, if you're data is in a data.frame called `df`:

```
df <- structure(list(Label = c("Charles", "Kevin", "Alan", "Alan", 
"Jim"), Jim = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Charles = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0), Kevin = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0), Alan = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("Label", "Jim", 
"Charles", "Kevin", "Alan"), row.names = c(NA, -5L), class = "data.frame")

df[outer(df$Label, names(df), '==')] <- 1
```

Comment: I think this matches the structure of the OP's data better than my answer (although a numeric matrix would probably be a better/slightly more efficient way to store such data ... it might even want to be a sparse matrix ...)

Comment: @BenBolker Yeah but you're is slick! I didn't know about `storage.mode`!

Answer (score 3):

There may be a faster way, but this should work reasonably well:

Data:

```
m <- matrix(0,nrow=5,ncol=4,
            dimnames=list(c("Charles","Kevin","Alan","Alan","Jim"),
            c("Jim","Charles","Kevin","Alan")))
```

Use `outer` to compare all rows with all columns:

```
mm <- outer(rownames(m),colnames(m),"==")
storage.mode(mm) <- "numeric" ## because as.numeric() loses matrix dimensions
dimnames(mm) <- dimnames(m)   ## reset row/column names
```